# Debugging android application on HTC Hero

Tags: android, adb, htc-hero

Is it possible to connect the ADB with an HTC Hero?  I tried following the instructions for the [Win USB driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) but when I try to install the driver I just get a generic message saying that there was a problem installing the driver.  Looking at the supported devices, the HTC Hero isn't listed.  Is this even possible?

As a note, I've tried removing drivers and then re-adding using USBDeview and I've also tried adding in the line ";HTC Hero
%USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0FFE.DeviceDescRelease%=androidusb.Dev, USB\Vid_0bb4&Pid_0ffe&Rev_0100" in the inf file for the driver.

Comment: Couldn't tell you on Windows but I can tell you that you can definitely connect to the Hero via ADB on OS X. I'd imagine you're having a general Android USB driver issue here, not an issue with the Hero specifically, so I'd troubleshoot accordingly.

Comment: This may not be related to your issue at all, but remember to enable Allow Debugging on the handset :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you just need to download the drivers from HTC that come with [HTC sync](http://www.htc.com/us/support/hero-sprint/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a driver from HTC. http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Drivers/HTC-Hero-Drivers-81097.shtml. Once you have these, you need to manually install through device manager in windows. Make sure you have Device Debugging enabled before you connect. You should now be able to use ADB. Twitter me if you need more help: superlinkx.

Comment: Those are Vista/Win7 drivers but I need XP.  I tried searching for these but couldn't find any.  Know of a place to get them?